# error when using RandomWPMobility, omnet++ simulation environment

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am following a tutorial for simulating wireless communication in omnet++  (version 5.1.1, on ubuntu 16.04, x64) using the AODV protocol (implemented as a part of the INET library).
I have used the following code:

```
*.host*.mobilityType = "RandomWPMobility"
*.host*.mobility.waitTime= uniform (100s,500s)
*.host*.mobility.speed = uniform(1mps, 10mps)
*.host*.mobility.updateInterval = 0.1s
```

when running the code i get an error:

> Cannot schedule message (omnetpp::cMessage)move to the past, t=-9.22337e+06 -- in module (inet::RandomWPMobility) Basic.hostA.mobility (id=39), during network initialization

Can someone please help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same error in this tutorial. I do not know exactly where it comes from, but here is the solution that I found:

omnetpp.ini

```
[Config TestRandomWPMobility2]
network = MobileNetwork

*.host[0].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp" # Protocole de communication
*.host[1].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPSink"    # hostMobB = jette les messages recus
*.host*.wlan[0].typename = "IdealWirelessNic"

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 600m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 400m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
**.updateInterval = 0.1s # test with 0s too, and let getCurrentPosition update the display string from a test module

*.numHosts = 5
**.host*.mobilityType = "RandomWPMobility"
**.host[0].mobility.speed = 10*uniform(20mps,50mps)
**.host*.mobility.speed = uniform(20mps,50mps)
**.host*.mobility.waitTime = uniform(3s,8s)
```

MobileNetwork.ned:

```
network MobileNetwork
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=600,400");
    submodules:
        host[numHosts]: MobileHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=400+50*numHosts,300+50*numHosts;r=,,#707070");
        }
}
```

I hope this will help you.